# Meteor.js JS flavor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I understand that Meteor.js uses ES2015, so there are a few new Javascript constructs that I'm getting used to. However, the code below confuses me:

```
Template.body.events({
  'submit .new-task'(event) {
    // ...
  },
  'change .hide-completed input'(event, instance) {
    // ...
  },
});
```

How is a function getting declared using the

```
'xxx yyy zzz'(args){ }
```

format? I tried running it in node.js, and it (as I thought) didn't work, and I can't imagine for the life of me, why it would.

Comment: It's the shorthand method declaration. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#Description

Comment: Note that according to [this compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions_shorthand_methods) that shorthand definition should also work in a modern Node version (not the one Meteor uses, but Meteor also uses Babel to make it compatible with its years-old Node version).